# How to list all the videos in a youtube channel using android studio.

Tags: android

I am building an android app to list all videos from a particular youtube channel.Can anybody give me the code to for that.

Comment: Read the youtube api documentation..https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list Try to impliment yourself and ask if you have any doubts.

Comment: This is not a code writing service. We volunteer our time to help people learn to do it themselves.

Comment: @sunil sunny ,there is a sample code for listing the videos in the link that you have given .But some of lines are not working. Especialy code to define global instance for youtube object is "private static YouTube youtube;" This line is showing error. I have included all required api file     "YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi" in my library and also I have an appliaction ID for my app.Then why this error is occuring.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to copy the entire sample code ,just call this link to get channels.
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videoCategories?part=snippet&hl=en&regionCode=US&key={YOUR KEY}
You will get a json response with all the channels or videocategories available.
Parse the response and you will get a "categoryId" from the response.

Then call this link to get the videolist for a particular categoryId
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?chart=mostPopular&part=snippet&type=video&videoCategoryId={a categoryId got from previous response }&maxResults=20&key={YOUR KEY}

parse the response.that's all.